# ControlCollection events? / OnControlRemoved (bulk / clear?)

Tags: c#, winforms

We are using a custom implementation of the `FlowLayoutPanel` because the one provided by the .net Framework is just awkward slow.

So, whenever a control is added / removed, we handle a incremental recalculation of coordinates in `OnControlAdded` respectively `OnControlRemoved`.

Now, if `flowLayoutPanel.Controls.AddRange(...)` or `flowLayoutPanel.Controls.clear()` is called, `OnControlAdded` respectively `OnControlRemoved` is called multiple times.

In case of `Clear()`, all we would have to do is set 4 variables to 0, rather than recalculating positions for every removal. We have a method `flowLayoutPanel.ClearControls()` for that, but now facing the issue of an external Library, that is directly invoking `flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Clear()` because it is obviously not aware of "our" implementation.

The `ControlEventArgs` of `OnControlRemoved` unfortunately do not provide any information, if it is a single removal, or a call to `Clear()` that has been issued.

So, I'm searching for a way, to be able to tell if `ControlCollection.Clear()` has been invoked.

Currently it seems that there is no way beside extending the `ControlCollection` class, implementing a proper event on `Clear()` and subscribe to that event from our FlowLayoutPanel. But before going that road, just wanted to ask, maybe there is some sort of generic `CollectionChangedObserver` that can be attached to the `flowLayoutPanel.Controls`-Collection and distingiush between `.Remove()` and `.Clear()`?

Comment: There's hope, these methods were a .NET 1.0 design mistake and get used incorrectly 99% of the time.  Destroy a control and remove it from any container it is hosted on by calling its Dispose() method.   It avoids a permanent memory leak when you forget to put the control back on another container.  And a significant slowdown when the leak builds up.  Use its Disposed event to get a notification.

Answer (score 1):

After spending quite some time looking at the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs), there is other way but to extend `ControlCollection` class and add events like "ClearStarts" and "ClearEnds", so that you can ignore the following removes in between, and only act on `ClearEnds`.

Comment: Or, since you're already replacing the existing class, you can override `OnControlRemoved` and not raise the event if the remove was the result of calling `Clear()` by setting a simple bool flag in code. Then you can raise just one new event called `ControlsCleared` or something like that, instead of counting on your consumers to avoid hanlding the `ControlRemoved` event

Comment: @ZoharPeled. what you suggest is not possible.  If you look into the source, you will notice that Clear calls RemoveAt multiple times, starting from the end, resulting in multiple OnControlRemoved calls.  In OnControlRemoved there is no way to tell who called you.

Comment: Not only is it possible it's actually very easy: You add one `private bool _IsClearing = false;` in your class, then override the `Clear` method like this: `override...Clear() {_IsClearing=true;base.Clear();_IsClearing=false;}` and override `OnControlRemoved` to only raise the event if `_IsClearing` is false: `override ...OnControlRemoved() {if(_IsClearing) return; base.OnControlRemoved();}`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, only that `Clear` is a method of `ControlCollection`, while the event `OnControlRemoved` belongs to `Control`.  You want to create state that is shareable across classes that are designed to interact without going so.

Comment: You're correct, I haven't noticed that.

Comment: @Nick that's exactly what i've done now. Was way easier than expected, posting as answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, i've now created a own implementation of the `ControlCollection`, used that within our implementation of the `FlowLayoutPanel`. Thx to the dedicated method `Control.ControlCollection.CreateControlsInstance` it was actually quite easy to "hook in" without messing too much with the original implementation:

```
public class ExtendedControlCollection : ControlCollection
{
    public event EventHandler OnBeforeClear;
    public event EventHandler OnAfterClear;

    public ExtendedControlCollection(Control owner) : base(owner)
    {
        
    }

    public override void Clear()
    {
        OnBeforeClear?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        base.Clear();
        OnAfterClear?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

and relevant parts of our `FlowLayoutPanel`:

```
    private Boolean IsClearingControls { get; set; } = false;
    private EventHandler OnBeforeClearHandler = null;
    private EventHandler OnAfterClearHandler = null;
    ...
    protected override Control.ControlCollection CreateControlsInstance()
    {
        this.OnBeforeClearHandler = (object o, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            this.IsClearingControls = true;
        };

       this.OnAfterClearHandler = (object o, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            this.FlowPositionX = 0;
            this.FlowPositionY = 0;
            this.FlowingHeight = 0;
            this.IsClearingControls = false;
        };

        ExtendedControlCollection ecc = new ExtendedControlCollection(this);
        ecc.OnBeforeClear += this.OnBeforeClearHandler;
        ecc.OnAfterClear += this.OnAfterClearHandler;

        return ecc;
    }
    ....

    protected override void OnControlRemoved(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnControlRemoved(e);
        if (!this.IsClearingControls)
        {
            //Recalculate positions for Controls based on removed control
            //else: Do nothing, clearing is handled in OnAfterClear() Listener.
        }
    }
    ...
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (this.OnBeforeClearHandler != null)
            {
                ((ExtendedControlCollection)this.Controls).OnBeforeClear -= this.OnBeforeClearHandler;
                this.OnBeforeClearHandler = null;
            }

            if (this.OnAfterClearHandler != null)
            {
                ((ExtendedControlCollection)this.Controls).OnAfterClear -= this.OnAfterClearHandler;
                this.OnAfterClearHandler = null;
            }
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to disconnect the two events in Control.Dispose().